# Copy elements in a doubly linked list to a singly linked list

Tags: java

I have a custom doubly linked list and I want to use an enhanced for loop to print elements in O(n) time. So I copied all the elements to a singly linked list but that takes O(n*2) time. Is there a more efficient way to copy elements?

Comment: Iterating a doubly linked list should take O(n) time. So should copying it. But you shouldn't need to copy it to iterate it. Why have you not posted any code?

Comment: `O(n) = O(n · 2)` by definition (you can choose constants to let both expressions equals)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a copy to print elements. Iteration of a linked list (doubly-linked or not) should be O(n):

```
List myList = createMyDoublyLinkedList();
for (Object item : myList) {
    System.out.prointln(item);
}
```

To better understand your question you would need to post the code you have.